# 2015 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Magento's [first moderator election](https://magento.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 3 new moderators are:

[image: Marius] [image: benmarks] [image: benmarks]

philwhinkle will be installed as a [moderator](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Please join me in thanking [Alex](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/81/alex), who is stepping down as *pro tem* moderator. We are incredibly grateful to all the moderators who helped guide this site through the pre-election period.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/5723399875723264/0).

Comment: Thank you @Alex for your awesome support so far. And congratulation winners -Marius -philwinkle -benmarks. Community won by the way :)

Comment: congrats Marius , Philwhinkle  , Benmarks

Comment: Thank you Alex for great support

Comment: Congrats, again! :-)

Comment: Congrats all! Great team

Comment: Congratulations guys!

Comment: Congrats all :)

Comment: grats to you all :) let's keep this thing rolling

Comment: Congrats to all :)

Answer (score 18):

Thank you all for participating. I am both humbled and grateful. For me it is business as usual - answer questions and vote. Let's get busy helping people and make this a great resource for the entire Magento community at-large!

[image]

Comment: congrts @philwinkle .Ben& marius

Comment: Congrats on your little diamond near your name. I really hope you are back "full time" on SE not just for moderating, but for answering also. I missed your answers.

Comment: Yes we really like you(r hair :P) and  can you please style your hair as diamond :P